# f3/Fatfree framework - Error on route second param

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

```
$f3->route('GET /index.php/@ctrl',
function($f3){
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        echo $f3->get('REDIR_LINK')['LOGIN'];
    }

    switch ($f3->get('PARAMS.ctrl')) {
        case 'admin':
        $f3->set('info', array(
            'title' => 'Administrator Page'
            )
        );
        echo View::instance()->render('admin.php');
        break;

        default:
        $f3->set('error404', DIR_ASSET.'images/404.jpeg');
        echo View::instance()->render('index.php');
        break;
    }
}
);
```

but when i change the route to

```
$f3->route('GET /index.php/@ctrl/@test ~~~~~
```

i can't access the page with only @ctrl, like /index.php/admin, but i still have a access to /index.php/admin/user

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include the actual error message you're getting.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is probably on [user's guide page](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine):

> Another thing: Fat-Free sees `GET /brew` as separate and distinct from the route `GET /brew/@count`.

My advice would be to try this:

```
$f3->route( 
    array(
        'GET /index.php/@ctrl/@test', 
        'GET /index.php/@ctrl'
    ),
    function($f3) { 
        ... 
    });
```